# How to use a C++ class in C?

Tags: c, c++11

I have a C++ class:

```
class foo{
  .
  .
  .
};
```

I want to use this in C code as below:

#### file.c

```
foo funct(class foo f){
  .
  .
  .
  return f;
}
```

Here I want to use C++ class in C function which receives a C++ class as an arg and return the same.

Comment: `class` is not a C keyword, so your function is not valid C.

Comment: only answer: you can't

Comment: Why? There may be a valid method to pass information between modules written in different languages that you can use.

Comment: C and C++ are compulsory to use.......Here I have C++ class and I want to receive its data members in C only...This is my requirement. Or I will have to do it like make a C structure corresponding to Class data members means C structure contain all data member that I have in class and assign the class data members to structure only and Now I am sure I can use use this in C. Is this the only and correct solution? or there may be a different solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can't call C++ class methods directly from C, but you can provide a set of wrapper functions declared and defined with the `extern "C"` declaration.  And then use a `void*` style cast approach to wrap each public method with a C function.

Here's a simple example of allowing a class called "Foo" to be linked with C code and invoked from it.

Foo.h

```
 #ifndef FOOCLASS_H
 #define FOOCLASS_H

 class Foo
 {
 public:
      int M1();
      int M2(int x);
 };

 #endif
```

FooWraper.h

```
 #ifndef FooWrapper_H
 #define FooWrapper_H

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

     void* createFoo();
     int Foo_M1(void* foo);
     int Foo_M2(void* foo, int x);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif

 #endif
```

FooWraper.cpp

```
 extern "C" void* createFoo()
 {
     Foo* foo = new Foo();
     return (void*)foo;
 }

 extern "C" void* deleteFoo(void* foo)
 {
     Foo* pRealFoo = (Foo*)foo;
     delete pRealFoo;
 }

 extern "C" int Foo_M1(void* foo)
 {
       return ((Foo*)foo)->M1();
 }

 extern "C" int Foo_M2(void* foo, int x)
 {
       return ((Foo*)foo)->M2(x);
 }
```

main.c

```
#include "FooWraper.h"

int main()
{
     void* foo = createFoo();
     Foo_M2(foo, 42);
     deleteFoo(foo);
}
```

Comment: instead of using `void*`, you could `#ifdef` a declaration of incomplete types `class Foo;` for C++ and `typedef struct Foo Foo;` for C; also, `createFoo()` should be declared as `void* createFoo(void);` - otherwise, C will accepts an arbitrary number of arguments without complaining...